# React Suspense makes network waterfall when a component fetches more than twice

Tags: reactjs, react-suspense

I'm using **react-query and set suspense `true`**.

I found that my web app became slow. That's because suspense makes **network waterfall**.
Below img is this case.

[network tab image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58A3W.png)

However when I configure suspense to `false`, it works in parallel.

[network tab image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJlyH.png)

I know that Suspense catches a Promise and shows Loading fallback until it is settled.
So I understand why it make waterfall.

Then, **is Suspense only useful as a page requests only one API call?**
Or, Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Suspense is only useful for when a page only requests one API call. If you need to make multiple API calls, you can use React.lazy() to load components dynamically.

Comment: Oh, thank you. You mean If I use React.lazy() each component and it calls API, it doesn't make waterfall?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. React.lazy() will only load the component when it is needed, so it won't make a waterfall of API calls.

Answer (score 0):

Suspense is only useful for when a page only requests one API call. If you need to make multiple API calls, you can use React.lazy() to load components dynamically.

```
React.lazy()
```

will only load the component when it is needed, so it won't make a waterfall of API calls.

Comment: Really? until now, I have used Suspense but I don't know that. I will test it. Thank for your answer!!

Comment: Can you help me? I tested it but I didn't get good result. I tried 3 case. First, 2 Query in 1 Component , Second, 1 Query in 1 Component, wrapped with a Suspense, Third, 1 Query in 1 Component, wrapped with each Suspense. You can check it in https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-euclid-6ld1yn . I wonder if it is possible that 2 Query in 1 component wrapped with Suspense can not make waterfall.